# Output audio is nothing but static

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, audio-processing

below is a code that takes an audio file, applies a filter to it then plays the sound back to the user. The "create audio" section of the code is supposed to take what was played in Python and output an audio file. When I listen to the outputted audio file, it is bunch of static and I am unsure what might be causing this

```
from io import BytesIO
import tempfile
import requests
import librosa
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sg
import pydub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Audio, display
import wave
%matplotlib inline

def speak(voice):
    audio = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(BytesIO(voice))    #takes audiofile     and creates a mutable file

    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fn:
        wavef = audio.export(fn, format='wav')
        wavef.seek(0)                            
        wave = wavef.read()

    x = np.frombuffer(wave, np.int16)[24:] / 2.**15     #creates a numpy array by taking info of audio from temp memory. 
    return x, audio.frame_rate


def play(x, fr, autoplay=False):
    display(Audio(x, rate=fr, autoplay=autoplay))




voice = open("pathToMp3", "rb").read()  

x, fr = speak(voice)
play(x, fr)

b, a = sg.butter(4, 500. / (fr / 2.), 'low')   
x_fil = sg.filtfilt(b, a, x)
play(x_fil, fr)


#create audio file
wav_out = wave.open("output2.wav", "wb")
wav_out.setnchannels(2) # stereo has 2 channels
wav_out.setframerate(44100)
wav_out.setsampwidth(2)

wav_out.writeframes(x_fil.tobytes())
wav_out.close()
```

Comment: when writing audio code always get it working first using mono ... here looks like you have jumped straight into stereo which is unnecessary here ... also I would comment out other non essential aspects like your butterworth filter ... always start with a known good in your case get it working by simply reading a mono ( one channel ) wav file into a memory buffer and then playing that buffer ... then build up complexity from that known good code base ... when you build from working code you immediately know what is cause of error as its what you just added

Comment: Noise might mean you are still playing MP3 data (compression) as if sound (PCM). Check the saved file with a **hex editor**. If after WAVE header (51 bytes) it is immediately followed by bytes `FF FB` then it is Mpeg compression data just put inside a `.wav` file.